# Website with Python API not deploying correctly on Github Pages

Tags: vue.js, github-pages, pythonanywhere

We are in a group project with 2 others and myself, and have implemented a CRUD using HTML, CSS, Vue.js, and an API on pythonanywhere, and put it on GitHub Pages. The problem is that it works great locally and it connects to pythonanywhere with no problems, but online, on Github Pages, it fails and throws an error message, I have tried everything I know, but nothing seems to load the saved products on pythonanywhere.

I know Github Pages has it´s particularities, but I can't seem to crack it yet. If anyone can help or explian what the problem is, that would be awesome.

Here is the link to the repo and the Github Pages website:

https://github.com/GasparB123/Codo-a-Codo-TPO

https://gasparb123.github.io/Codo-a-Codo-TPO/productos_crud.html

I know Github Pages is picky about the route to images and js files, so I fixed them

Example

Changing "/img/logo.png" to "img/logo.png".

But that didn't work.

I thought it could be an issue of conflict between HTTP on pythonanywhere, and the HTTPS Github Pages deployment, but if that is the issue, I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Make requests to `https://pablodelapuente.pythonanywhere.com/productos` not `http://pablodelapuente.pythonanywhere.com/productos`

All webapps on `<username>.pythonanywhere.com` have https enabled by default. On custom domains one has to enable it. See https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/HTTPSSetup